# R: melt data to collapse 3 columns into 1 column and double that for each row

Tags: r, reshape2

I have a data like the following:

```
 df1
 id count white_v pink_v others_v 
 1  1     0.4      0.5   0.6
 1  2     0.5      0.5   0.747
 1  3     0.87     0.57  0.87
 2  1     1.5      2.5   1.2 
 ....
```

and I want to reshape the data in a way that it is compatible to another data frame of the following format:

```
 df2
  id count white pink
  1    1   1      0 
  1    1   0      1
  1    1   0      0
  1    1   1      0
  1    1   0      1
  1    1   0      0
```

so basically, I want to append the values of pink, white, others from df1 to df2, but df2 is formatted in the way that each color is dummy coded (0,0 from both pink and white implies that column is for others). And for each purchase of each customer, df2 has 6 rows for that with the first three rows being a repetition of the first 3.

What I want to achieve is a data frame like the following:

```
 df3
 id count white pink   v
  1  1    1     0      0.4 -> indicates the value of white_v for id 1,count1
  1  1    0     1      0.5 -> indicates the value of pink_v for id 1, count1
  1  1    0     0      0.6 -> indicates the value of others_v for id 1, count1
  1  1    1     0      0.4 -> indicates the value of white_v for id 1,count1
  1  1    0     1      0.5 -> similarly as above
  1  1    0     0      0.6
```

I need to iterate through through each person and each purchase count for them. I have thought of using loops but I got stuck in terms of how to use i to index both the row of df1 and df2. Then I also thought about using reshape but I am not sure how I can achieve this.

Would greatly appreciate any insights.

Comment: In my opinion, that (df2's formatting) is a bad idea. Much better to have a factor column with "white", "pink" or "other" in it rather than these redundant 0/1 vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tidyr and dplyr,

```
library(tidyverse)

        # gather colors into long key and value columns
df1 %>% gather(color, v, white_v:others_v) %>% 
    # drop "_v" endings; use regex if you prefer
    separate(color, 'color', extra = 'drop') %>% 
    # add a vector of 1s to spread
    mutate(n = 1) %>%    # more robust: count(id, count, color, v)
    # spread labels and 1s to wide form
    spread(color, n, fill = 0)

##    id count     v others pink white
## 1   1     1 0.400      0    0     1
## 2   1     1 0.500      0    1     0
## 3   1     1 0.600      1    0     0
## 4   1     2 0.500      0    1     1
## 5   1     2 0.747      1    0     0
## 6   1     3 0.570      0    1     0
## 7   1     3 0.870      1    0     1
## 8   2     1 1.200      1    0     0
## 9   2     1 1.500      0    0     1
## 10  2     1 2.500      0    1     0
```

Comment: but the desired result I want is that after I got the first three rows, I will repeat the three rows once and then continue.. the format of df3 is what I want

Comment: Manually repeating to make it line up is a really, really bad idea. Use a join instead. As Frank mentioned, that's probably easier in long form.

Comment: Another interesting alternative: `df1 %>% gather(color, v, white_v:others_v) %>% model.matrix( ~ . - 1, data = .) %>% as.data.frame()`